# SQL Trigger on Insert to call a Function and Manipulate Values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having a problem knowing set up a trigger on insert to call a function and passing an identifier `SiteID` to that function which then operates on variables from another table.

I have the table, where values are inserted:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tests] (
   [Id]     INT       IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
   [SiteID] NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
   [Date]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
   [Time]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
   [Tub]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
   [FCl]    FLOAT (53)     NOT NULL
   PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Every time a value is inserted in to the `Tests` table I would like a function to be called which uses the table `Review` to perform a simple calculation (see the trigger down the post below):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Review] (
   [SiteID] NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
   [TubNum] INT NOT NULL,
   [Supplied]  INT  NULL,
   [Performed] INT  NULL,
   [Remaining] INT  NULL 
   PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([SiteID] ASC)
);
```

This is my [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7141e) so far, however, I am unable to save it with the functions I am working on, which are here:

The trigger - not sure how to pass the SiteID for the insert or call the function:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TRIG_MyTable]
ON [dbo].[Tests]
AFTER INSERT
 AS
   CALL CalcRemaining() //how to pass it SiteID?
```

and the the function itself:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CalcRemaining](@ID NVARCHAR (128))
RETURNS NULL
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT (Supplied, Performed FROM Review WHERE SiteID = ID);
   Performed = Performed + 1;
   INSERT INTO Review (Performed, Remaining) VALUES (Performed, (Supplied-Performed))
RETURN;
END
```

The idea is that the `SiteID` from the inserted line is passed to the function when called, the function then `selects` the values `Supplied` and `Performed` for that matching `SiteID` from the `Review` table. The `Performed` value is incremented by 1 and that new value along with the retrieved `Supplied` value are subtracted and written to the `Remaining` field in the `Review` table.

Comment: you can try it and pass it to method `CalcRemaining(SELECT i.[SiteID]
           FROM inserted i;)`

Comment: Why are you storing dates and times using `NVARCHAR(MAX)`?  SQL Server has good support for date/time types.

Comment: I wasn't aware that SQL Server allowed functions to modify other tables in the database.  Use the function to calculate the value.  Use the trigger to insert the value into the `Review` table.

Comment: Should `Remaining` always be `Supplied - Performed`? If so, a computed column would do a better job here. Is `Performed` always the count of the number of rows in `Test` for a given `SiteID`? If so, a View that computes this value would be indicated. Taken together, those could completely remove the need for a trigger/function. In short, don't *manually* calculate data that can be easily (re-)computed.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - apologies for the delay. Yes, you are correct in your assumptions, this is a neater approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the assumptions I've asked about in the comments are valid (that `Remaining` and `Performed` can always be calculated), here's how I'd implement your database structure, with no trigger nor function:

Base tables:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Tests (
   [Id]     INT       IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
   [SiteID] NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
   [Date]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
   [Time]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
   [Tub]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
   [FCl]    FLOAT (53)     NOT NULL
   PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo._Review (
   [SiteID] NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
   [TubNum] INT NOT NULL,
   [Supplied]  INT  NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([SiteID] ASC)
);
```

Then a view that calculates `Performed`:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo._Tests_Count
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT
        SiteID,
        COUNT_BIG(*) as Performed
    FROM
        dbo.Tests t
    GROUP BY SiteID
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_Tests_Count ON dbo._Tests_Count (SiteID)
```

And finally a view that re-creates the original `Review` table:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.Review
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT
        r.SiteID,
        r.TubNum,
        r.Supplied,
        COALESCE(tc.Performed,0) as Performed,
        r.Supplied - COALESCE(tc.Performed,0) as Remaining
    FROM
        dbo._Review r
            left join
        dbo._Tests_Count tc WITH (NOEXPAND)
            on
                r.SiteID = tc.SiteID
GO
```

If needed, at this point a trigger could be created on this `Review` view to allow any `INSERT`s, `DELETE`s and `UPDATE`s to be performed against it rather than `_Review`, if you cannot change some calling code.

Comment: I have tried producing this in sqlfiddle [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d0d21) but I get a syntax error around `CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_Tests_Count ON dbo._Tests_Count (SiteID)`

Comment: Thank you this solution works perfectly. I do not fully understand the syntax, but this is my homework, at least I have a solution I can learn from :-)

Answer (score -1):

You have to be completely sure you're manipulating ONLY one row at a time!

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TRIG_MyTable]
ON [dbo].[Tests]
AFTER INSERT
 AS
DECLARE @SiteID NVARCHAR (128)
SELECT @SiteID = ID FROM inserted
   CALL CalcRemaining(@SiteID)
```

Comment: Your comment indicates you know this is not a very good answer. A trigger MUST be able to handle multiple row operations, otherwise it is a poor implementation.

Comment: @SeanLange Yes I know, but I don't know which is the framework and so i suggested a quick solution that solves his problem, if and only if he has the correct side conditions (only one row at a time)

Comment: The condition of only a single row operation is never going to be true. Even if that is true today there is nothing preventing an application or system change in the future that will break this type of trigger. I know of at least one company that actually went under because their triggers did not handle multiple row operations and a major system changed exposed the problem and fixing it was such a major undertaking they couldn't get it done.

Comment: Yes, this would be an instant fail if it came up for code review for me. If there was a long comment at the start that explained *why* it couldn't support multi-row inserts *and* it raised a descriptive error if it encountered a multi-row insert (rather than silently failing), it *might* be accepted. But not if the "why" is "I didn't want to spend time making it work"

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever You're right, i could have managed the multirow insert. The only thing it is not correct is the "why" that is: "unfortunately i do not have time to explain in depth since I'm also a little busy on other tasks". May be it would have been better not to answer rather than giving an answer requiring additional understanding on their side (I'm not ironic)