# MS SQL Computed column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to create a column based on COUNT(*) on another table, and when a record is deleted from that table it should decrease the value in this new column and vice versa. So, here is the query:

> SELECT COUNT (*) FROM dbo.Korisnik1_FakturaStavka GROUP BY dbo.Korisnik1_FakturaStavka.FakturaID

And it returns this: [image]

And when I try to create a computated column like this:

> CREATE TABLE test(
>       NumberOF as (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM dbo.Korisnik1_FakturaStavka GROUP BY dbo.Korisnik1_FakturaStavka.FakturaID)  )

I get the following error:

```
Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed.
```

Here is the main table that I want to compute from:

[image]

How can I resolve this ?

Comment: First of all... bad idea...not formalized...why do you want to keep a data in the db that can be calculated easily...?  If you really want to do that, I suggest to use a trigger associate with the addition or deletion of a row in the other table...but this can become time consuming for the server if it's a table that have a lot of "activities" in it

Comment: You can create an [Indexed View](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx) that does the counting and then, if you need this data to appear in another table, you can create a further *view* that looks like the final table you wanted but just joins the table (without the computed column) to the indexed view.

Comment: (For an example of this, I've just posted an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30917244/15498) to another question with a similar requirement)

Comment: I want to keep that number because I am not able to make second auto-increment column, so that second column StavkaBroj has to be 1,2,3... depends on FakturaID, example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786665/mysql-second-auto-increment-field-based-on-foreign-key and now from that number that I keep, I will just increase it manually and assign it to StavkaBroj

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever ye this might solve the problem, i thought there is a simpler way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too long for a comment.

You can do this by defining a function to calculate the count and using that function in the computed column definition.  However, I don't think this is a good idea for frequently used columns, because you will be doing a lot of counting "behind the scenes".

Alternatives:

- Set up a view or materialized view with the additional count column.
- Do the count explicitly when you need it.
- Set up a trigger to store the count in the first table, whenever rows are inserted/updated/deleted from the second table.

Comment: Right, this seems to be a way better approach than mine

Answer (score 1):

You *can* define a UDF:

```
create function dbo.NumberOfFakturaID(@id int) returns int as begin
  return (select count(1) from Korisnik1_FakturaStavka where id=@id)
end
```

and then use it as the computed column:

```
CREATE TABLE test(FakturaID int, NumberOF as dbo.NumberOfFakturaID(FakturaID))
```

But putting that sort of calc as a computed column should be used with care.

Comment: Thanks this is what I needed but right this is a bad idea probably so its better to make view and trigger whenever the rows are affected.

Comment: In part it depends on how you want to use this. If you need to check it constant you might want to keep the running totals via a trigger. But if you only get it occasionally maybe the view is better. If you actually don't actually are in an environment that never has folks doing SELECT * then the UDF isn't tragic.